# Using change of variables to find joint density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

$X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables with parameter λ. We want to find joint distribution of $(U,V)$ where $U=X+Y$ and $V=X/Y.$ Then find marginal dist of U and V.

I was thinking of using change of variables to solve this but i'm having trouble at several steps. This is what I have so far:

$f_{(x,y)} (x,y)= λ^2e^{-λ(x+y)}$

$u=x+y$, $v=x/y$

$x=\frac{uv}{v+1}$, $y=\frac{u}{v+1}$

Region K: $(0,\infty)^2$, Region L: $\{(u,v): 0<u<\infty, ?<v<? \}$ (how do i find bounds?)

$J_k(x,y) = \frac{-x-y}{y^2}$ (is this right?)

Then $f_{u,v}(u,v) = f_{(x,y)} (\frac{uv}{v+1},\frac{u}{v+1})*\frac{1}{|J_k(\frac{uv}{v+1},\frac{u}{v+1})|}=$ $\frac{λ^2 e^{-λu}u}{(v+1)^2}$ (is this right?)

Comment: $v\in (0,\infty )$

Comment: Does everything else look right?

Comment: I remember I did the same mistake when I was asked to do this question the first time.